# Unathorized WGet inside docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to install the `jenkins/jenkins` image in ubuntu 18.04 for a few days and I'm never able to make the container able to access the internet.

I've already done this on a Windows 10 machine without any issues.

The command I'm using is `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts` that I've found in this [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md)

When I try to do some simple wget I've noticed there is a 401 Unathorized in every single request.

What Have I tried:
- I've cleared up iptables to allow INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD.
- UWF is disabled.

What can cause this?

-- Edit:
The commands I've tried:
host
wget www.google.com success
wget https://updates.jenkins.io/2.150/latest/additional-metrics.hpi success
guest
wget www.google.com (returns 401)
wget https://updates.jenkins.io/2.150/latest/additional-metrics.hpi (return 404)

It gets even weirder because gradle is able to retrieve dependencies but apt is not able to find anything

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access the internet? Does wget work on the host?

Comment: I don't use any proxy. And it works on host

Comment: what wget command are you running

Comment: wget https://updates.jenkins.io/2.150/latest/additional-metrics.hpi (return 404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is surprisingly stupid.

It so happens in the same machine as the docker container, homestead was being run at port 80 in and out.